# How to login to ssh with capistrano, run a couple of commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

instead of the standard capistrano deploy flow for a rails app, I just want mine to login to my server via ssh (I have a key setup), cd to the app, run svn update, run migrations and then restart Passenger.

However, I am having difficulty finding any good documentation to start me along the right path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be something like this?

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :upgrade, :roles => [:app] do
    invoke_command "cd #{current_path} && svn up"
    invoke_command "cd #{current_path} && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
    invoke_command "cd #{current_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

Could be cleaner I guess...

The wiki is quite good: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki

Comment: Interesting ... so to call this I would just run cap deploy:upgrade right?